# We have always been around

Tags: riddle, rhyme

We can come day or night
In darkness or light.

Sometimes in pairs, sometimes more
We sneak up on you as you move for the door

We can dance we can jump we can bounce and we can roll
We can put on a show but we won't have control

**Who are we?**

First hint

> We follow you though you aren't always aware we are there

Comment: this looks like the classic shadow riddle...  but in darkness also...

Comment: Given the OP's handle, shouldn't this be titled "Always been around, we have"? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answered before, but here's another attempt.
The answer could be

> Your shadow(s)

We can come day or night
In darkness or light.

> Obviously during the day, but unless it is 100% dark you will always technically have a shadow even if you can't see it.

Sometimes in pairs, sometimes more

> Multiple light scources can cause multiple shadows

We sneak up on you as you move for the door

> If you have a lamp above your door the shadow will be cast behind you. As you move closer to the door and lamp the shadow will shrink until being fully beneath you when you are standing directly under the lamp.

We can put on a show but we won't have control

> Plenty of ways for light to create dancing shadows, for example a (camp)fire will create a show of shadows. The shadows are oviously not in control themselves.

Comment: Thats correct, nice work. thecoder16 mentioned this last month but no one picked up on it strangely.

Answer (score 5):

I think it is

> A pair of Footwear

We can come day or night
In darkness or light

> People can come or go in footwear any time of the day/night

Sometimes in pairs, sometimes more
We sneak up on you as you move for the door

> We wear a pair of footwear while going out (can be more than one person)

We can dance we can jump we can bounce and we can roll
We can put on a show but we won't have control

> People can dance/jump/roll with a pair of footwear but footwear does not have any control

Answer (score 3):

You are

> LEGS.

We can come day or night
In darkness or light.

> Every living creature with legs have always legs.

Sometimes in pairs, sometimes more.

> Not all creatures have two legs, but also none of them has one. So you come either as pairs, or more.

We sneak up on you as you move for the door

> When somebody (or some animal) moves for the door (or anything), the legs are the main instruments. Thus, they follow.

We can dance we can jump we can bounce and we can roll
We can put on a show but we won't have control

> Dancing, jumping, bouncing can be done with legs, but they don't have the control. The brain controls them.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is

> Footsteps or footprints

Mostly because of the reasons listed by the others.
I think "We sneak up on you" rules out the previous answers

> As footwear and legs are attached to you, whilst footsteps actually follow you (sneak up on you)